# How do i build a simple time series display in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to Shiny and I'm trying to build a small app to plot 3 time series with X being day of the year and Y being price and the 3 lines being 2018 and 2019 actual price and the third being a model predicted price.

The data frame I'm working with looks kind of like this

```
City        Day_of_year avg_price price type
Rome        1           400       sold_2018
Rome        2           405       sold_2018
Milan       1           300       sold_2018
Milan       2           305       sold_2018
Rome        1           200       sold_2019
Rome        2           200       sold_2019
Milan       1           205       sold_2019
Milan       2           205       sold_2019
Rome        1           200       prediction_2020
Rome        2           200       prediction_2020
Milan       1           205       prediction_2020
Milan       2           205       prediction_2020
```

I would like the UI to have a select input based on city as the only reactive element. i.e. Rome will display the 3 lines for Rome, Milan for Milan etc..

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example? If you never used R Shiny, you might prefer to start [with this tutorial](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/)

Comment: https://myweather.ch/2018/08/swissmetnet-timeseries-diplayed-in-a-r-shiny-app/

this above was my inspiration. something similar but with a single plot. The three time series will have to exist at the same time on the plot while the only change would be the city. Unfortunately i can't really reproduce the df. I've already started learning Shiny from the link you provided but i'm really stuck on this particular idea. I understand it's a long shot to get help here but thought it was worth a try!

Comment: I will help you, do not worry. I will give you and example in a moment.

Comment: what you could put in your post is: the base code for a shiny app (automatically provided by Rstudio when you create a new shiny app), a database provided in R (```iris```, ```mtcars```...) so that everybody can access it, some comments in the code that say what you want... That may seem useless, but if people just have to copy-paste some code directly in Rstudio to have an idea of what you want to do, you will have much more help than just saying in words your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@praguetastic Always is a good idea to share a reproducible example of your data. the function `dput` from base R is ideal to do this. In case your data big, just try to make a sample data that keeps the importat elements of your question, like I show next.

**data**

It is important that you let people know the way your data is stored, since this way we can use the correct approach to help you. For example, in this case I do not know if you have timeseries object or a data frame like this.

```
data <- data.frame(
  country = rep(c("Dom. Rep", "USA", "China"), each = 50),
  price = rnorm(150, mean = 1, sd = 6),
  date = rep(seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), by = "day", length.out = 50), times = 3)
)
```

**app**

If your run this script, you'll have a simple app to start doing what your want.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(

  #Header
  h1("Time series plot"),

  selectInput(
    inputId = "country",
    label = "Select country",
    choices = unique(data$country),
    selected = "Dom. Rep"
  ),

  plotOutput("plot")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    data %>%
      filter(country == input$country) %>%
      ggplot(aes(date, price)) +
      geom_line()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the future, remember to improve your questions. This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) can be useful for that

Comment: thanks 10000! I understand what you're saying about reproducible examples, I'm new to Stack Overflow too and I will definitely read up some before I post again! 

That being said somehow you managed to understand my nonsense and delivered something I will need to slightly modify but it's pretty much what I need! Again, thanks a lot!